# Rails transaction with relational dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception, transactions

I'm having some trouble with transactions in Rails 3. Basically I have two models (Project and Membership)

```
@project = Project.new(params[:project])
@project.user = current_user

membership = Membership.new
membership.project = @project

Project.transaction do
  begin
    @project.save!
    membership.save!
  rescue
    flash[:notice] = "There was an error creating your project."
  end
end
```

I am creating a new project and trying to immediately create a membership for the project (membership does actually also have a relation to the a User model, n:m).

Now I'm starting a transaction to save the project and the membership inside the transaction. Problem is that I'm getting an exception:

> Validation failed: Project can't be blank
>
> app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:64:in `block in create'
>
>   app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:61:in`create'

Line 61 is `Project.transaction do`

Comment: Show your project and membership models including the relationships between them, plus the relevant validations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out myself. The Membership model validates the presence of :project_id. I am setting membership.project before I save the project inside the transaction. After that I am trying to save the membership, but as the project was set before it was created in the database the :project_id is nil.

In order to fix this code I had to rearrange it like this:

```
membership = Membership.new

Project.transaction do
  begin
    @project.save!
    membership.project = @project
    membership.save!
  rescue
    flash[:notice] = "There was an error creating your project."
  end
end
```

Note that the assignment of `@project` is now **after** the project has been saved (and an ID has been automatically generated).

Comment: Just out of interest, does it work in your original form if you validate presence of :project, rather than :project_id?